# Django - Foreign key to another app with a complex name

Tags: django, django-models, django-paypal

I'm writing a Django Model that will link to another app Model. I know that we should link the ForeginKeys with "nameoftheapp.nameofthemodel" but I'm not successful doing it with this use case.

Here is my installed_apps:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'signup',  
    'paypal.standard.ipn',
    ... 
)
```

Basically I'm creating a model in the app "signup" and I need to do a foreignkey to "paypal.standard.ipn".

Here is my model:

```
class SignupPaymentPayPal(models.Model):
    gettingstarted = models.ForeignKey('GettingStarted')
    paypalipn = models.ForeignKey('paypal.standard.ipn.PayPalIPN')
```

The model I need to link is this one, https://github.com/spookylukey/django-paypal/blob/master/paypal/standard/ipn/models.py

When I try to do a shemamigration I got this:

```
$ python manage.py schemamigration signup --auto
```

Here is the error I got:

```
CommandError: One or more models did not validate:
signup.signuppaymentpaypal: 'paypalipn' has a relation with model paypal.standard.ipn.PayPalIPN, which has either not been installed or is abstract.
```

Any clues on what I'm doing wrong?

Best Regards,

Comment: Have you tried to reference imported module?: `from paypal.standard.ipn.models import PayPalIPN; ... ; paypalipn = models.ForeignKey( PayPalIPN )`

Comment: You are rigth! It worked with paypalipn = models.ForeignKey( PayPalIPN ). Not worked with paypalipn = models.ForeignKey('PayPalIPN') that I've tested previously.

Comment: You want I post it as answer in order you check it as solution?

Answer (score 2):

```
from paypal.standard.ipn.models import PayPalIPN

class SignupPaymentPayPal(models.Model):
    gettingstarted = models.ForeignKey('GettingStarted')
    paypalipn = models.ForeignKey(PayPalIPN)
```

Answer (score 2):

André solution works, and in fact I'd recommend using the actual model instead of a string whenever possible, to avoid any unexpected errors when the string can't be resolved to a model, but here's an explanation why your previous method didn't work:

Django has a model cache that keeps track of all Model subclasses that are created. Each model is uniquely identified by an appname and modelname, but not by a fully qualified import path.

Let's say I have two models, one is `myapp.reviews.Review`, the other is `myapp.jobs.reviews.Review`. If `myapp.reviews.Review` comes first in my `INSTALLED_APPS`, both classes will actually be the `myapp.reviews.Review` model:

```
>>> from myapp.jobs.reviews import Review
>>> Review
<class 'myapp.reviews.Review'>
```

To specify a `ForeignKey` using a string instead of a class (e.g. to avoid circular imports), you need to follow the `'<appname>.<modelname>'` format, i.e.:

```
class SignupPaymentPayPal(models.Model):
    paypalipn = models.ForeignKey('ipn.PayPalIPN')
```